# How to add variable pane in intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone know how to add the variable pane in intelliJ? I closed it by accident I cant find how to re-open it.

This is were it used to be but now I only have the "watches":
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this every now and then, and it always takes me way too long to get it back...see the stack-looking icon toward the top-right corner, under the icon next to settings? That should do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Click that icon to restore layout]

Click on the restore layout icon to see watch pane /variable pane and call stack pane.